# How i can solve this error mongo db when insert operation?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

## Error : MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [nodeMongoCrud.users]

`server is running on port 5000 MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [nodeMongoCrud.users] at Connection.onMessage (G:\web-development-projects-list\milestone-11\node-mongo-crud-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:207:30) at MessageStream.<anonymous> (G:\web-development-projects-list\milestone-11\node-mongo-crud-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:60:60) at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28) at processIncomingData (G:\web-development-projects-list\milestone-11\node-mongo-crud-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:132:20) at MessageStream._write (G:\web-development-projects-list\milestone-11\node-mongo-crud-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:33:9) at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12) at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10) at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10) at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22) at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) { ok: 0, code: 8000, codeName: 'AtlasError', [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {} }`

I create second user on mongodb and  copy the configuration from  mongodb. then replace  and  .

then i try to add an  create an object on datbase with this funciton below: `

But I got an error That i highlight on title .

Answer (score 0):

To create or modify a database user, please go to cloud.mongodb.com and go to the Database Access tab and make sure that your user has the readWriteAnyDatabase@admin access so you can read or write the data in your MongoDB database with…